# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException from [applicationContext-mytutorial.xml]

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am doing tutorial related to spring, hibernate, and maven.
and got `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException` error message.
Here is the link to tutorial:

http://www.lulu.com/shop/arulkumaran-kumaraswamipillai-and-sivayini-arulkumaran/tutorial-java-maven-2-eclipse-jsf/ebook/product-1603040.html;jsessionid=0C532C55C373D3DDB01AC49ACE23A5E2

As I go through this tutorial after I put hibernateTemplate stuff into the code.

I did exactly what the tutorials said.

but I keep getting this error. Even if I was getting an error I kept going on writing the rest of the code into eclipse.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'courseService' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-mytutorial.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-mytutorial.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-mytutorial.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionFactory]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.mytutorial.App.main(App.java:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-mytutorial.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-mytutorial.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionFactory]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-mytutorial.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionFactory]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2283)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2279)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1748)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1788)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:814)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:732)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate specified TransactionFactory class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringTransactionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(TransactionFactoryInitiator.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(TransactionFactoryInitiator.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:176)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringTransactionFactory cannot be cast to org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionFactory
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(TransactionFactoryInitiator.java:77)
    ... 56 more
```

Here is my applicationContext-mytutorial.xml.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="courseService" parent="txnProxyTemplate">
        <property name="target">
            <bean class="com.mytutorial.CourseServiceImpl" scope="prototype">
                <property name="courseDao" ref="courseDao" />
            </bean> 
        </property>

    <property name="preInterceptors"> 
        <list>
            <ref bean="traceBeforeAdvisor" /> 
        </list>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="courseDao" class="com.mytutorial.CourseDaoImpl" scope="prototype"> 
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" 
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory"> 
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="txnProxyTemplate" abstract="true" 
        class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
            <property name="transactionManager"> 
                <ref bean="transactionManager" />
            </property>
            <property name="transactionAttributes">
                <props>
                    <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                </props> 
            </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" 
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" 
        scope="singleton">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" /> 
    </bean>

    <!-- Advice classes -->
    <bean id="tracingBeforeAdvice" class="com.mytutorial.TracingBeforeAdvice" />

    <!-- Advisor: way to associate advice beans with pointcuts --> 
    <!-- pointcut definition for before method call advice --> 
    <bean id="traceBeforeAdvisor"
            class="org.springframework.aop.support.RegexpMethodPointcutAdvisor"> 
            <property name="advice">
                <ref local="tracingBeforeAdvice" /> 
            </property>
            <property name="pattern"> 
                <value>.*\.process.*</value>
            </property> 
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is my CourseServiceImpl.java

```
package com.mytutorial;

import java.util.List;

public class CourseServiceImpl implements CourseService {

    private CourseDao courseDao;

    public CourseDao getCourseDao(){
        return courseDao;
    }

    public void setCourseDao(CourseDao courseDao){
        this.courseDao = courseDao;
    }

    @Override
    public void processCourse(List<Course> courses) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //CourseDao dao = new CourseDaoImpl();
        courseDao.create(courses);
        List<Course> list = getCourseDao().findAll(); 
        System.out.println("The saved courses are --> " + list);
        } 
}
```

Here is my CourseDaoImpl.java

```
package com.mytutorial;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

public class CourseDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements CourseDao {


    @Override
    public void create(List<Course> listCourses) {
        HibernateTemplate ht = getHibernateTemplate();

        for (Course course : listCourses) {
            ht.save(course);        
        } 

    }

    @Override
    public List findAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HibernateTemplate ht = getHibernateTemplate(); 
        return ht.find("From Course");  
    }
}
```

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration> 

    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property> 
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost</property> 
        <property name="connection.username">SA</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>


        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) --> 
        <property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on start-up, also try with “update” to keep the previous values -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> 


        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="com/mytutorial/Course.hbm.xml"/> 
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is my App.java

```
package com.mytutorial;

import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext-mytutorial.xml");

        List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>(10);

        Course c1 = new Course(); 
        c1.setName("John"); 
        c1.setCourse("Java");

        courses.add(c1);

        Course c2 = new Course(); 
        c2.setName("Peter"); 
        c2.setCourse("Hibernate");

        courses.add(c2);

        //CourseService service = new CourseServiceImpl(); // tightly coupled 
        CourseService service = (CourseService) ctx.getBean("courseService");
        service.processCourse(courses);
    }
}
```